# C# Using a static saveFileDialog1.Filename string in a different void

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So I have done many trials, many google searches and read many overflow questions before coming and asking here.

I am not a Pro in C# but i have a basic understanding of it all.

So I have a C# Windows Forms Application, with one of my forms(form2), i am stuck.

This form is basically a UPDATER form, it reads an XML file on my website(using XMLTextReader), checking for a newer version of the app and if there is one it downloads it(with a full already working WebClient).

I know it's probably not best to check for updates this way as if there is a lot of people downloading the update at once, its going to screw up, however this is a private app only used by my friends and myself.

So what i have done is i made strings(DOWNLOADPath) and (SAVEPath). The SAVEPath is the saveFileDialog1.Filename and the DOWNLOADPath is the download link in my xml file.

I am not sure if this is correct/safe but I make these strings accessible outside of their Voids, so i used: "string SAVEPath { get; set; }" and "string DOWNLOADPath { get; set; }".

This was working well in every test i do, i haven't ran into any issues, however the one issue i do run into is when the download starts if the user cancels i can cancel the process fine, however i cannot delete the file it already 1/2 downloaded, and i need to delete this as the file would be corrupt if it is only half downloaded.

When i use the following:

```
if (e.Cancelled == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
    //Need to delete the file as if user cancels, the file will only be partially downloaded.
    if (File.Exists(SAVEPath))
    {
        File.Delete(SAVEPath);
    }
}
```

and this of coarse doesn't work because the file path doesn't exist in the string anymore, so is there a way to make the SAVEPath get the saveFileDialog1.FileName?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//Need the below to be able to download
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

//Need below to access XML
using System.Xml;

//Need the below to add sound
using System.Media;


namespace Downloader
{
    public partial class Download : Form
    {
        WebClient webClient;               // WebClient that will be doing the update downloading.
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();    // The stopwatch which used to calculate the download speed

        public Download()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

        //Check for update file, after form is shown.
        string DOWNLOADPath { get; set; }
        private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string downloadUrl = "";
            Version newVersion = null;
            string xmlUrl = "http://mywebsite/Update.xml";
            XmlTextReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlUrl);
                //dont read uneccasary lines, skip to main content in file
                reader.MoveToContent();
                //store element name
                string elementName = "";
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "DoWnloadTest"))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //if i find element node, store the name for later use.
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {
                            elementName = reader.Name;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //The text inside the xml if not empty txt file
                            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
                            {
                                //switch to element name.
                                switch (elementName)
                                {
                                    case "version":
                                        newVersion = new Version(reader.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "url":
                                        downloadUrl = reader.Value;
                                        DOWNLOADPath = downloadUrl;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }
            label1.Text = "Current version: v" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version + ".";
            label2.Text = "Newest version: v" + newVersion + ".";
            Version applicationVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            if (applicationVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
            {
                downloadVersionLabel.Text = "Status: Version" + newVersion.Major + "." + newVersion.Minor + "." + newVersion.Build + "." + newVersion.Revision + " of '" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "' is available, would you like to download it?";
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                downloadVersionLabel.Text = "Status: Your version of '" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "' is up to date.";
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

                // The variable that will be holding the url address (making sure it starts with http://)
                Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);

                // Start the stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the download speed
                sw.Start();

                //Disable the start button, don't want client accidently downloading multiple files
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;

                try
                {
                    // Start downloading the file
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        // The event that will fire whenever the progress of the WebClient is changed
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            labelSpeed.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            // Show the percentage on our label.
            labelPerc.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
            labelDownloaded.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }

        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        public void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Enable the start button
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;

            //Reset the stopwatch.
            sw.Reset();

            //Change the labels back to 0.
            labelDownloaded.Text = "0 MB's / 0 MB's";
            labelPerc.Text = "0%";
            labelSpeed.Text = "0 kb/s";

            //Set progressbar percentage back to 0.
            progressBar.Value = 0;

            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
                //Need to delete the file as if user cancels, the file will only be partially downloaded.
                if (File.Exists(SAVEPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(SAVEPath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download complete, newest version is located at: " + Environment.NewLine + "'" + SAVEPath + "'.");
            }
        }

        string SAVEPath { get; set; }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Creates a new instance of the SaveFileDialog and Show it.
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogUPDATE = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveFileDialogUPDATE.Filter = "Application (*.exe)|*.exe";
            saveFileDialogUPDATE.Title = "Update Test - UPDATE: Please select where to save the newest version.";
            saveFileDialogUPDATE.FileName = "Update";

            if (saveFileDialogUPDATE.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Make the user(s) chosen saving location a string.
                string SAVEPath = saveFileDialogUPDATE.FileName;

                // If the saveFileDialogUPDATE name is not an empty string use it for saving and do "DownloadFile".
                if (SAVEPath != "")
                {
                    DownloadFile(DOWNLOADPath, SAVEPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: You need to specify where to save the update.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.webClient != null)
            {
                this.webClient.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Any advice on this would be great cheers.

Comment: First of all, don't name forms as Form1, Form2 etc. Give your buttons proper names. It's impossible to know what `buttom1_Clicked` is supposed to be. And why wouldn't the filename be in that property anymore? What errors you get since you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Look at the coding conventions to give your variables proper names : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen your right i shouldn't name my forms form1, form2 etc. For myself to test, i temporally called it form2, before i posted my current solution i renamed to "Download" you can tell by reading the code. I don't know what you mean about: buttom1_Clicked. I certainly have not used that. No errors, just as said the saveFileDialog was returning nothing, because i clumsily made it a string, going over the code with it in my face i didn't even realize this whole time... Sybren, I should give my variables proper names, just trying to get this form to work, i will cleanup my code at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this line:

```
string SAVEPath = saveFileDialogUPDATE.FileName;
```

Creates a *local variable* which, coincidentally, has the same name as your `SAVEPath` property.

I suspect what you intended was to set your property:

```
SAVEPath = saveFileDialogUPDATE.FileName;
```

And then the file name will be accessible from other methods.

Comment: WOW!!! I knew i was missing something simple haha.... Cheers @Charles Mager